# Recursively find a view of a specific type iOS

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, uiview, subview

I have a `UIView` I want to parse all the subviews of the view and return the instance of subview that is of type `CustomClass`

With `view.subviews` I only get to immediate subviews , I want to parse all subviews and return my subview that matches a condition.

```
findView(key : uniqueKey , view : UIView)

for subview in view.subviews {
if subview.uniqueKey == key 
return subview       // and break 
else 
continue with recursively searching
}
```

I know I need to solve this recursively but I am sure that only one instance of this view is present so as soon as I find the instance I would want to return and break the recursion.

How can I achieve the same.

Comment: view contains it may only one match subview or it may be multiple?

Comment: No since the key is unique it will match only one subview

Answer (score 4):

You can use this generic UIView extension method to find any object of specific class. It returns nil if no subview exists of that class.

```
extension UIView {
    func find<T:UIView>(_ ofType:T.Type) -> T? {
        if let test = subviews.first(where: { $0 is T }) as? T {
            return test
        } else {
            for view in subviews {
                return view.find(ofType)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let firstBtn = self.view.find(UIButton.self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function with view tag, you can replace it with your unique key.

```
func findView(tag :Int, view : UIView) -> UIView? {
    if view.tag == tag {
        return view
    }

    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let v = findView(tag: tag, view: subview) {
            return v
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func findView(key: String, view: UIView) -> UIView? {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if subview.key == key {
            return subview
        } else {
            return findView(key: key, view: subview)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note: key isn’t defined on UIView so the logic for locating assumes you’ve defined that via a protocol or extension

Answer (score 0):

you want to fund your custom view using uniqueKey, then use the following function to get the result as your requirement.

```
func findView(key : uniqueKey , view : UIView) -> customView? {
        var fondSubview:customView!

        for subview in view.subviews {
            if subview.uniqueKey == key {
               fondSubview = subview as! customView
                break
            }
        }        
        return fondSubview
    }
```